# Spring Server returning 404 and not running scheduled tasks

Tags: java, spring

I have a spring server that is running a few scheduled tasks at startup as well as a simple endpoint. The endpoint looks like:

```
@PutMapping(value = "/api/publisher/apis/{API_ID}/serviceUrl")
    public void redirectService(@PathVariable("API_ID") String apiId, InputStream urlStream) throws Exception
    {
        System.out.println("Redirected app id: " + apiId);
    }
```

When I try to touch it with a postman put request, the console reads:

```
2019-07-25 07:52:52.665  INFO 39320 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2019-07-25 07:52:52.665  INFO 39320 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2019-07-25 07:52:52.669  INFO 39320 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 4 ms
```

In addition to this, non of the scheduled tasks are running, there is nothing syntactically wrong in the code because it worked before i refactored the folders around which broke the program. I tried adding a few test `@Bean`s but they too are not starting up. What could have gone wrong when refactoring the Spring app. Does spring rely on specific folder names to find the controller and other similar files?

Comment: Is the route stored in any ```@Controller``` or in a ```@RestController``` ?
Is this bean [scanned](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-component-scanning) or manually inserted in the ```@Configuration``` ?

Comment: As mentionned, "refactor directories" won't change the scanned packages in your spring config ```@ComponentScan(...)``` as they are listed in a String

Comment: again yes the actual code is correct, it was unchanged from when it was working, apart from the fact that I had changed the directories in the project

Comment: Then you have to check oyur spring ```@Configuration``` which scans old paths (previous comment)

Comment: UPDATE: the controller only works when placed in the same directory as the Application.java

Comment: going to delete this and ask a more accurate question

Answer (score 2):

Spring doesn't rely on folder name to find the controller but it does rely on base packages from which spring beans are scanned which can be specified by using annotation `@ComponentScan` .
As `@Service` `@Controller` `@Repository` `@Component` all does specify that those classes are beans with name specific functionality.